# Trying to connect with R to Snowflake with ODBC error

Tags: r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to Snowflake with R:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
     "SnowflakeDSII"                 
)
```

OR

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
    Driver       = "Snowflake",
    Server       = "*.snowflakecomputing.com",
    UID          = "*",
    PWD          = "*",
    Database     = "*",
    Warehouse    = "*",
    Schema       = "PUBLIC"
)
```

But constantly get this error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib' : file not found

I use `iODBC Data Source Administrator` to test the connection of DNS that I have setup and it says:

> The connection DSN was tested successfully, and can be used at this time.

I am  macOS Big Sur, Apple M1 chip with R 4.1.0

#### Update

content of the `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Snowflake = Installed

[Snowflake]
Driver = /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib
```

#### Update 2

If I run the same script with Rscript under `sudo`, I get different error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified 
Execution halted
```

Comment: Please share the entries in  /Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini file.

Comment: Does the odbc.ini file under /Library/ODBC have the similar entries:


[ODBC Data Sources]
SnowflakeDSII = Snowflake

[SnowflakeDSII]
Server = <account.region>.snowflakecomputing.com
Schema = <schema>
Warehouse = <WG>
Driver = /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib
Description = Snowflake DSII
Locale = en-US
Tracing = 5
Database = <DB>
Password = <PWD>
tracing= 5
LogLevel =5
LogPath = <Path>

This is what I have in my system with which I am able to connect from RStudio.

Comment: Yes, that file is set up in a similar way and when I test this connection from ODBC Administrator, it works fine

Comment: actually it works fine from `iODBC Adminstrator64` but not the `iODBC Adminstrator` which complains about the driver location, but does not say where it is trying to find it.

Comment: Uninstall the iODBC Administrator and have only the 64 one. That should clear out any of the overlapping configuration for R-Studio to reference. Then test the connectivity from R and provide the results.

Comment: Uninstall of iODBC admin did not change anything. I don't think RStudio is aware of troubleshooting tools.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a reference issues with the drivers... the 64-bit driver was probably installed 2nd. I'd remove both drivers and only install one.